# Error: Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, get, data-retrieval

I am working with Flutter and I have added some data to a Firestore collection, and now I want to retrieve values from the collection which are relevant to the user logged in.

The method I have drafted for retrieving data is:

```
Future<void> discoverUser() async {
      FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      final cDocRef = dB.collection('c/ubojjWZCZ/cDetails').doc('userAge');
      final pDocRef = dB.collection('p/sgujWHR5/pDetails').doc('userAge');
      try {
        if (_auth != null) {
         await cDocRef.get().then(
                  (DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
                final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                if (doc != null) {
                  userAge = data['userAge'];
                  if (userAge < 20) {
                    await pDocRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                      final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      if (doc != null) {
                        userAge = data['userAge'];
                      }
                    },
                    onError: (e) => print('Error getting document $e'),
                    );
                  }
                }
              },
              onError: (e) => print('Error getting document $e'),
      );
        }
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
```

The error message from Flutter is:

```css
E/flutter (23028): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
E/flutter (23028): #0      _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.discoverUser.<anonymous closure> (package:choice_hi/screens/login.dart:45:45)
E/flutter (23028): #1      _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.discoverUser.<anonymous closure> (package:choice_hi/screens/login.dart:44:23)
```

I am unsure of what is wrong with my code.  Could you advise me of how to fix it so that data from the collection can be retrieved please?

At this stage I am also uncertain about the Firestore security rules that I need in order for the data request to be approved by Firestore.  Could you also offer some general advice on the type of permission I need to allow please?

When I began writing the method, I was using the 'get' function and then I changed to 'doc.data()'.  Is it at all possible to rely on 'get' to retrieve one item of data from a collection please?

Many thanks for your time and your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is:

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

That comes from one of the two lines in your code that looks like this:

```
final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>
```

It seems that the document doesn't have any data (so it doesn't exist), and your code doesn't handle that.

The way to check whether the document you got exists is with [`doc.exists`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/exists.html) **before** calling `data()` on it.

So:

```
await pDocRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    userAge = data['userAge'];
  }
  else {
    print('Document does not exist');
  }
},
onError: (e) => print('Error getting document $e'),
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Frank ... I haven't tried this yet because I am looking into a completely new way that I hope to understand better, however, I do trust in your expertise : )

Comment: If doc.exists returns a false, what could be the solution in terms of Firestore security rules where the relevant collection is called 'collectionA' please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there, given that this wasn't about security rules so far. You might want to open a new question for the problem with your security rules, and include a new [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will do as you have suggested.